# помогите с редактированием кода (вывод изображения выбранного пункта в списке)

Tags: javascript, php, css

Здравствуйте уважаемые участники сообщества!
Прошу помочь с редактированием кода.
Раньше добавляемые элементы в админке на сайте отображались горизонтально, как меню. Элементы выводились на сайте с помощью этого участка кода:

```html
{% for system in payment_systems if system.id != 6 and system.id != 9 and system.id != 10 %}
   <label class="btn btn-for-toggle text-left" {% if system.group %}data-group="{{ system.group }}"{% endif %} onclick="return setPaymentSystem({{ system.id }});">
   <img src="{{ system.getIcon() }}" alt="" witht="50" height="50">
   {{ system.title }}  {{ system.short_title }}
   </label>
   {% endfor %}
```

(есть так же такие же элементы которые прописаны в коде то есть статичные, но вопрос не по ним, а именно по генерируемым элементам код которых предоставлен выше)

Я хочу переделать так, что бы элементы можно было выбрать с появляющегося списка, все это работает как реализовал код ниже:

```js
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  
  'use strict';
  
 var $html = $('html');
  
  $html.on('click.ui.dropdown', '.js-dropdown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
  });
  
  $html.on('click.ui.dropdown', '.js-dropdown [data-dropdown-value]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $item = $(this);
    var $dropdown = $item.parents('.js-dropdown');
    $dropdown.find('.js-dropdown__input').val($item.data('dropdown-value'));
    $dropdown.find('.js-dropdown__current').text($item.text());
  });
  
  $html.on('click.ui.dropdown', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if (!$target.parents().hasClass('js-dropdown')) {
      $('.js-dropdown').removeClass('is-open');
    }
  });
  
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
.c-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.c-dropdown__list {
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 6px 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 125%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: opacity .25s linear, top .25s linear;
}
.c-dropdown.is-open .c-dropdown__list {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 100%;
}

.c-dropdown__item {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #434A54;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  transition: background-color .25s linear;
}
.c-dropdown__item:hover {
  background-color: #E6E9ED;
}

/**
 * Component: Button
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
.c-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  font: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
.c-button:hover, .c-button:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.c-button:not(:disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/**
 * Component: Button
 * Modifier: Dropdown
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
.c-button--dropdown {
  padding: 6px 34px 6px 12px;
  background-color: #967ADC;
  color: #E6E9ED;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  min-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}
.c-button--dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #AC92EC;
}
.c-button--dropdown:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #E6E9ED;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c-dropdown js-dropdown">
      <input type="hidden" name="Framework" id="Framework" class="js-dropdown__input">
      <span class="c-button c-button--dropdown js-dropdown__current">Выберите валюту</span>
      <ul class="c-dropdown__list">
         <li class="c-dropdown__item" data-dropdown-value="angular">Pay</li>
         {% for system in payment_systems if system.id != 6 and system.id != 9 and system.id != 10 %}
         <li class="c-dropdown__item" data-dropdown-value="backbone" img src="{{ system.getIcon() }}" alt="" witht="50" height="50" {% if system.group %} data-group="{{ system.group }}"{% endif %} onclick="return setPaymentSystem({{ system.id }});">{{ system.title }}  {{ system.short_title }}<img src="{{ system.getIcon() }}" alt="" witht="50" height="50"></li>
         {% endfor %}
         <li class="c-dropdown__item" data-dropdown-value="ember">Pay</li>
         <li class="c-dropdown__item" data-dropdown-value="knockout">Pay</li>
         <li class="c-dropdown__item" data-dropdown-value="react">Pay</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

сейчас при открытии списка там иероглифы но на сайте все хорошо, подтягиваются и добавленные с админки элементы и их картинки, Но вопрос в другом!
При выборе определенного элемента функция работает, все работает, но в не отображается его картинка, то есть только название выбранного элемента, кто может помочь с этим?
Прошу только не ставить минус этому вопросу, лучше уже просто пропустите.

Answer (score 0):

У вас для получения url(ссылки) на изображение вызывается функция фрерймворка:

```
<img src="{{ system.getIcon() }}" ...
```

Возможно предполагается что в функцию нужно передавать название иконки

```
<img src="{{ system.getIcon('edit-icon') }}" ...
```

Но это только предположение, потму что код этой функции я не видел, попробуйте найти её и посмотреть.

Ещё вот в этом участке кода:

```
<li class="c-dropdown__item" data-dropdown-value="backbone"  img src="{{ system.getIcon() }}" ...
```

кажется не хватает скобочек закрывающих и открывающих теги

```
<li class="c-dropdown__item" data-dropdown-value="backbone"> <img src="{{ system.getIcon() }}" ...
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, скобки пропустил, перепроверю по поводу иконки, спасибо